# How to dynamically distinguish mapbox-gl and mapbox-gl-csp?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mapbox-gl-js

I need to create two projects for different security environments using two mapbox distributions, one with mapbox-gl and one with mapbox-gl-csp, repectively.

I have

```
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";
```

where I can determine which mapbox distribution file to import using build script.
The problem that I am having is, I'd like to distinguish which mapbox distributions that I am using, as I need to assign worker for the csp version.

I tried to use

```
    if ((mapboxgl as any).workerUrL) {
       mapboxgl["workerUrl"] = url;
    }
```

But it didn't work as `(mapboxgl as any)` is undefined for both mapbox-gl and mapbox-gl-csp before I assigned the worker. `typeof (mapboxgl as any).workerUrL` also didn't worker as both return undefined as well.

Therefore, I am wondering if there's any way that I can easily distinguish which mapbox distribution I am using?